# What's the difference between int *p = &a and q = &a

Tags: c, pointers

Learner question. I can declare and initialize a pointer in two different way

```
int a = 10;
int *p = &a;
```

also

```
int a = 10;
int *q;
q = &a;
```

I want to know what is the difference between two and how does it work in the memory?

Comment: what makes you think there is a difference

Comment: @TimCastelijns The syntax of initializing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those two are the same :

```
int *p; // declaration
p = &a; // assignment
```

and in the other you are combining the two steps together into one:

```
int *p=&a; // declaration and assignment
```

And if you have some compiler optimizations ON, the compiler might combine the two steps.

Comment: `p = &a;` is an assignment, not an initialization.

Comment: `int *p=&a;` is an initialization, not just a "declaration and assignment." There are differences between assignments and initializations; for example, objects with static duration may only be initialized with constants.

Answer (score 3):

Your two pieces of code are equivalent - there is no difference.

Generally for any type `T`, any variable name `x` and any expression `exp`, `T x = exp;` and `T x; x = exp;` are equivalent to each other.

Comment: I want to know why they are, though their syntax are different.

Comment: @tintinmj They are because they are. The syntax `T foo = bar;` is defined to define a variable and assign a value to it and the syntax `T foo; foo = bar;` is defined to do the same. That's just how the language is defined. Other than the fact that it makes sense that way and is what most people would expect, there is no "why" to it beyond that.

Comment: So there are no difference at memory?

Comment: @tintinmj Right, there is no difference in memory.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is **initialization** while the second one is **assignment**. Technically they are both very different operations that happen to use the same operator, with very different meanings - in C the `=` sign is, if you will, "overloaded".

In this case it will translate into the same behavior.

---

The standard defines them separately. In this case there are no differences but sometimes there are. For example when the object has static storage you can **initialize** it only to literals and constant expressions, while you can easily **assign** other stuff to it. There are more differences and it all boils down to the fact that they are **different operations** that for some reason use the same sign.

Comment: "Technically they are both very different operations" Can you explain that technical difference?

Comment: @sepp2k I added some explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference as such in both ways. Both do the same thing.
In first you are initializing at the time of declaration. In next one, you defer initialization.
both are doing the same thing i.e. storing address of variable 'a'.
About how does it work in memory. 'a' has its memory allocated(2/4 bytes) and stores its value at this location. The address of the first byte is stored in 'p'/'q' using &a(i.e address of a) which itself has memory allocated.

To retrieve value using pointer, you can use *p/*q(i.e. value at the address stored in p)