# What is the difference between the assignments to pointers in C?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

```
//C - code 
int num
int *pi = &num; //1 
printf(" *pi=%d  and  pi=%d \n ", *pi, pi);  // p1
pi = &num;      //2
printf(" *pi=%d  and  pi=%d \n ", *pi, pi);  // p2
```

As for comment `2`, I understand that we are assigning a valid address to the pointer pi but I don't understand what is happening in the line of comment `1` because because both the `printf()` statements `p1` and  `p2` are doing the same job.

And in case of **dynamic memory management** with *malloc(sizeof(datatype))* function, why the following is an invalid approach?

```
int *pi;
*pi = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); // terminates the program
```

while the following:

```
int *ri = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

and

```
int *qi;
qi = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

works fine.

Please explain.

**EDIT :** The question marked as duplicate to this question doesn't talk about pointers  and problems that we face during dynamic memory management.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialization vs Assignment in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35662831/initialization-vs-assignment-in-c)

Comment: @Michi please re- read the problems again.

Comment: Your'e using the wrong format specifier. `%p` is for pointers, not `%d`

Comment: @StoryTeller I understand. Would you please focus on the context!! I will improve my mistake in printf() function's format. Thanks.

Comment: So you mean that assigment and initialization apply different on Pointers?

Comment: How can this program compile? It should throw a warning like cast not assign a value of type `int*` to type `int`?

Comment: "*Would you please focus on the context!!*", I would if you had used less exclamation marks. That comes off as really entitled.

Comment: @Michi  If I were an expert, I would certainly be not here. And YES the duplicate marked problem  DOESN"T answer my original problem.

Comment: @AmirHasan: Your code invokes undefined behaviour. _Focus_ on writing code which is **not allowed** to do anything it wants - including formatting your disc! Your question is answered by a beginner's C book.

Comment: It happens because you edited your damn Question. Roll it back and see what happens.

Comment: The dup states clear that an initialiser is not an assignment. If you read that and try to understand you can answer your question yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between int \*p = &a and q = &a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767095/whats-the-difference-between-int-p-a-and-q-a)

Comment: @Michi I don't have time to waste.

Comment: @Olaf I know. but I am not getting how *pi = &num and pi = &num are different.

Comment: So get a better C book. Sorry, but we are no tutorial site. A pointer is not the same as the type it points to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting confused between the use of *** in the declaration of a pointer** and the use of *** as the dereferencing operator**.

To understand better, while declaring, you can write int `*p` as `(int*) p`.
This means, that p is of type 'pointer to an int'.

However, `*` is also the dereferencing operator, or the 'value at' operator. 
So, `*pi` = value at pi, i.e., the value stored at the location of num, i.e., the value of num.

```
int *pi;
*pi = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

crashes becuse you try to assign the result of `(int*)malloc(sizeof(int))` to the location where pi is pointing. but as pi is not pointing anywhere (it is uninitialized), hence, it doesn't work.

On the other hand,

```
int *ri = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

works because you are making `ri` point to the location where the result of `(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));`  is stored.

```
int *qi;
qi = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

also works because you are making qi point to the location where `(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));` is stored.

Comment: what is happening in the background in cases of  int *pi = &num;   And    pi = &num;  ?

Comment: When `pi = &num` , it means, pi is pointing to the location of num.
When `*pi = &num` , it means the value at pi is the address of the location of num. or in other words, the location at which pi is pointing will contain the address of num.

Answer (score 1):

You should understand what is a pointer.

A pointer should hold a valid memory address.

```
int *p;
```

Here `p` is a pointer which holds the memory address and `*p` is called dereferencing a pointer. In other words `*p` gives the value stored in the location `p`.

So during dynamic memory allocation

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) );
```

Here pointer `p` is assigned the address returned by `malloc()`.

```
int *p;

p = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Again pointer is being assinged the value returned by `malloc()`. Note that I am not using `*p` because still memory is not allocated for my pointer `p`

```
int num;
int *p = &num;
```

Assignment is proper but before intializing the variable if you deference then you get erroneous results.

```
int num = 10;
int *p = &num;
```

Now `*p` gives 10.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *pi;
*pi = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); // terminates the program
```

So you define a pointer variable without initializing it. It now contains an unspecified address. You then try and *write* to that *unspecified* address. That's undefined behavior according to the standard, and your run-time is kind enough to crash, so you'd know there's a problem.

```
int *qi;
qi = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

You again define a pointer variable, which again holds an unspecified address. But in the very next line, you assign *to the variable* some (probably valid) address. So all is well (so far).

So you you see, the two cases are different. In the first, you de-reference the pointer and assign to that (unspecified address), and in the second you assign to the pointer.

Answer (score -1):

The last time I programmed in C was more than 10 years ago, but AFIK, your first example crashes, because you assign the result of the malloc() to *pi (you try to assign the result of malloc to the address pi currently points to. Since *pi was not initialized, this crashes your program).

Comment: " you try to assign the result of malloc to the address pi currently points to"-  Would you please elaborate it more. I had read this earlier too but could not understand. I think this is what I am looking for.